# Is there a way to get a stock's financials or earnings numbers into google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

For example, get the quarterly numbers from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is built client side (not server side) by javascript, you need to grab the json from the source code and parse it by

```
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}};)/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

you can then be able to retrieve all the data.